# I need to create a html form with required text input. How I can do it?

Tags: google-apps-script

I do a form with htmlService but I need to validate the fields for make it obligtory.

Please give me some ideas ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the HtmlService you'll need to write some custom JavaScript that checks certain form fields for values when the form is submitted or button pressed.